# SwiftUI: How to get continuous updates from Slider

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm experimenting with SwiftUI and the Slider control like this:

```
struct MyView: View {

    @State private var value = 0.5

    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $value) { pressed in
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get continuous updates from the `Slider` as the user drags it, however it appears that it only updates the value at the end of the value change.

Anyone played with this? know how to get a SwiftUI Slider to issue a stream of value changes? Combine perhaps?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In SwiftUI, you can bind UI elements such as slider to properties in your data model and implement your business logic there.

For example, to get continuous slider updates:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final class SliderData: BindableObject {

  let didChange = PassthroughSubject<SliderData,Never>()

  var sliderValue: Float = 0 {
    willSet {
      print(newValue)
      didChange.send(self)
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView : View {

  @EnvironmentObject var sliderData: SliderData

  var body: some View {
    Slider(value: $sliderData.sliderValue)
  }
}
```

Note that to have your scene use the data model object, you need to update your `window.rootViewController` to something like below inside SceneDelegate class, otherwise the app crashes.

```
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView().environmentObject(SliderData()))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tried this yet, but it's the direction I want to go with a seperate model and view.

Comment: That works, but in the code I'm playing with at the moment, I want to get the value inside the current view and deal with it there. Any ideas?

Comment: @drekka You can access current value anywhere in the view using $sliderData.sliderValue.  Doesn’t that work?

Comment: Yeh that does work, but I'm trying to access it within the Slider view only. Not through an environment object. I'll post some code shortly for comment as I've got it working.

Comment: To get this to work in the latest Xcode : BindableObject -> ObservableObject -  Xcode 11.3

Comment: Also add **@Published** to the sliderValue in the ObservableObject

Comment: I entered a new answer using onEditingChanged, an argument of Slider. It's a lot simpler than thi sone.

Answer (score 13):

We can go without custom bindings, custom `init`s, `ObservableObject`s, `PassthroughSubject`s, `@Published` and other complications. Slider has `.onChange(of: perform:)` modifier which is perfect for this case.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56921048) can be rewritten as follows:

```
struct AspectSlider2: View {

    @Binding var value: Int
    let hintKey: String
    @State private var sliderValue: Double = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {

            Text(LocalizedStringKey("\(hintKey)\(value)"))

            HStack {
                Slider(value: $sliderValue, in: 0...5)
                    .onChange(of: sliderValue, perform: sliderChanged)
            }
        }
    }

    private func sliderChanged(to newValue: Double) {
        sliderValue = newValue.rounded()
        let roundedValue = Int(sliderValue)
        if roundedValue == value {
            return
        }

        print("Updating value")
        value = roundedValue
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great and it makes what I was looking for. A Continuous update of Slider. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

After much playing around I ended up with the following code. It's a little cut down to keep the answer short, but here goes. There was a couple of things I needed:

- To read value changes from the slider and round them to the nearest integer before setting an external binding.
- To set a localized hint value based on the integer.

```
struct AspectSlider: View {

    // The first part of the hint text localization key.
    private let hintKey: String

    // An external integer binding to be set when the rounded value of the slider
changes to a different integer.
    private let value: Binding<Int>

    // A local binding that is used to track the value of the slider.
    @State var sliderValue: Double = 0.0

    init(value: Binding<Int>, hintKey: String) {
        self.value = value
        self.hintKey = hintKey
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {

            // The localized text hint built from the hint key and the rounded slider value.
            Text(LocalizedStringKey("\(hintKey).\(self.value.value)"))

            HStack {
                Text(LocalizedStringKey(self.hintKey))
                Slider(value: Binding<Double>(
                    getValue: { self.$sliderValue.value },
                    setValue: { self.sliderChanged(toValue: $0) }
                    ),
                    through: 4.0) { if !$0 { self.slideEnded() } }
            }
        }
    }

    private func slideEnded() {
        print("Moving slider to nearest whole value")
        self.sliderValue = self.sliderValue.rounded()
    }

    private func sliderChanged(toValue value: Double) {
        $sliderValue.value = value
        let roundedValue = Int(value.rounded())
        if roundedValue == self.value.value {
            return
        }

        print("Updating value")
        self.value.value = roundedValue
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks for the example of custom binding.

Comment: Thank you, it's what I was looking for  FYI: It's not "setValue" / "getValue" anymore. Now it's "set" and "get" parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I am not able to reproduce this issue on iOS 13 Beta 2. Which operating system are you targeting?

Using a custom binding, the value is printed for every small change, not only after editing ended.

```
Slider(value: Binding<Double>(getValue: {0}, setValue: {print($0)}))
```

Note, that the closure (`{ pressed in }`) only reports when editing end starts and ends, the value stream is only passed into the binding.

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me. The problem I'm having now is that even though I drag the slider button and it logs the values, the button doesn't actually move across the display. Weird. Ahhh.... just worked out why :-)

Comment: @drekka why isn't the slider knob moving?

Comment: Because the get closure of the binding always returns 0 in this reduced example. There is no chance for it to have any other value. You have to store the current value somewhere, for example in a @State variable.

Answer (score 2):

In Version 11.4.1 (11E503a) & Swift 5. I didn't reproduce it.
By using Combine, I could get continuously update from slider changes.

```
class SliderData: ObservableObject {

  @Published var sliderValue: Double = 0
  ...

}

struct ContentView: View {

  @ObservedObject var slider = SliderData()

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Slider(value: $slider.sliderValue)
      Text(String(slider.sliderValue))
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS 13.4, Swift 5.x

An answer based on [Mohammid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3815069/mohammad-reza-farahani) excellent solution, only I didn't want to use environmental variables.

```
class SliderData: ObservableObject {
let didChange = PassthroughSubject<SliderData,Never>()

@Published var sliderValue: Double = 0 {
  didSet {
    print("sliderValue \(sliderValue)")
    didChange.send(self)
   }
  }
}

@ObservedObject var sliderData:SliderData

Slider(value: $sliderData.sliderValue, in: 0...Double(self.textColors.count))
```

With a small change to ContentView_Preview and the same in SceneDelegate.

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
      ContentView(sliderData: SliderData.init())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about like this:

**(1)** First you need the observable ...

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

// make your observable double for the slider value:
class SliderValue: ObservableObject {
    @Published var position: Double = 11.0
}
```

**(2)** When you make the slider, you have to PASS IN an instance of the observable:

So in HandySlider it is declared as an ObservedObject. (Don't forget, you're not "making" it there. Only declare it as a StateObject where you are "making" it.)

**(3)** AND you use the "$" for the Slider value as usual in a slider

(It seems the syntax is to use it on the "whole thing" like this "$sliderValue.position" rather than on the value per se, like "sliderValue.$position".)

```
struct HandySlider: View {

    // don't forget to PASS IN a state object when you make a HandySlider
    @ObservedObject var sliderValue: SliderValue

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("0")
            Slider(value: $sliderValue.position, in: 0...20)
            Text("20")
        }
    }
}
```

**(4)** Actually make the state object somewhere.

(So, you use "StateObject" to do that, not "ObservedObject".)

And then

**(5)** use it freely where you want to display the value.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    // here we literally make the state object
    // (you'd just make it a "global" but not possible in playground)
    @StateObject var sliderValue = SliderValue()

    var body: some View {

        HandySlider(sliderValue: sliderValue)
            .frame(width: 400)

        Text(String(sliderValue.position))
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

#### Test it ...

Here's the whole thing to paste in a playground ...

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

class SliderValue: ObservableObject {
    @Published var position: Double = 11.0
}

struct HandySlider: View {
    @ObservedObject var sliderValue: SliderValue
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("0")
            Slider(value: $sliderValue.position, in: 0...20)
            Text("20")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var sliderValue = SliderValue()
    var body: some View {
        HandySlider(sliderValue: sliderValue)
            .frame(width: 400)
        Text(String(sliderValue.position))
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

### Summary ...

- You'll need an **ObservableObject** class: those contain **Published** variables.
- Somewhere (obviously **one** place only) you will literally make that observable object class, and that's **StateObject**
- Finally you can use that observable object class anywhere you want (as many places as needed), and that's **ObservedObject**

### And in a slider ...

In the tricky case of a slider in particular, the desired syntax seems to be

```
Slider(value: $ooc.pitooc, in: 0...20)
```

ooc - your observable object class

pitooc - a property in that observable object class

You ***would not*** create the observable object class inside the slider, you create it elsewhere and ***pass it in*** to the slider. (So indeed in the slider class it is an observed object, ***not*** a state object.)

Answer (score 0):

### If the value is in a navigation, **child** view:

Here's the case if the slider is, say, a **popup** which allows you to adjust a value.

It's actually simpler, nothing needs to be passed in to the slider. Just use an `@EnvironmentObject`.

Don't forget environment objects must be in the ancestor chain (you can't unfortunately go "sideways").

### EnvironmentObject is only for parent-child chains.

Somewhat confusingly, you can't use the simple EnvironmentObject system if the items in question are in the same "environment!" EnvironmentObject should perhaps be named something like "ParentChainObject" or "NavigationViewChainObject".

EnvironmentObject is only used when you are using NavigationView.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport
// using ancestor views ...

class SliderValue: ObservableObject {
    @Published var position: Double = 11.0
}

struct HandySliderPopUp: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sv: SliderValue
    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $sv.position, in: 0...10)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var sliderValue = SliderValue()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination:
                  HandySliderPopUp().frame(width: 400)) {
                    Text("click me")
                }
                Text(String(sliderValue.position))
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(sliderValue) //HERE
    }
}
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Note that **//HERE** is where you "set" the environment object.

For the "usual" situation, where it's the "same" view, see other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, this is what I did:

```
struct DoubleSlider: View {
  @State var value: Double
  
  let range: ClosedRange<Double>
  let step: Double
  let onChange: (Double) -> Void
  
  init(initialValue: Double, range: ClosedRange<Double>, step: Double, onChange: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
    self.value = initialValue
    self.range = range
    self.step = step
    self.onChange = onChange
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    let binding = Binding<Double> {
      return value
    } set: { newValue in
      value = newValue
      onChange(newValue)
    }
    
    Slider(value: binding, in: range, step: step)
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
  DoubleSlider(initialValue: state.tipRate, range: 0...0.3, step: 0.01) { rate in
    viewModel.state.tipRate = rate
}
```

Comment: You don't need a custom `init` here. You don't need `return` inside `get` block of `Binding`. You don't need a custom `Binding` to implement `onChange` functionality, because `Slider` already has `.onChange(of: perform:)` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
Slider(value: Binding<Float>(get: {quantity}, set: { qty in
    quantity = qty
    print(quantity)
}), in: 1...100)
```

making Palle's answer a bit more ready to use

Answer (score -1):

Just use the onEditingChanged parameter of Slider. The argument is true while the user is moving the slider or still in contact with it. I do my updates when the argument changes from true to false.

```
struct MyView: View {

    @State private var value = 0.5

    func update(changing: Bool) -> Void {
        // Do whatever
    }

    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $value, onEditingChanged: {changing in self.update(changing) }) 
        { pressed in }
    }
}
```