# How to bind an EnvironmentObject variable to a slider

Tags: swiftui

I have a sliderVal that needs to be accessed in various other places, so my understanding is that I should use a EnvironmentObject (or BindableObject, but EnvironmentObject was nice because this is used in the subviews as well) to hold those values. Something like this

```
struct ExampleView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var externalData : ExternalData

    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: self.externalData.$sliderVal, from: 1, through: 100, by: 1)
    }

}

final class ExternalData : BindableObject {

    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<ExternalData, Never>()

    var sliderVal : Double = 5.0 {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
}
```

This usually works for things like Text, however here, when I try to use the $ symbol to bind to something like a Slider, it gives a compile error of

```
Value of type 'ExternalData' has no member '$sliderVal'; did you mean 'sliderVal'?
```

But using just sliderVal gives me the error

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'Binding<_>'
```

Trying to use @State for sliderVal in my enviroment object builds successfully, but gives me this error at runtime

```
Fatal error: Accessing State<Double> outside View.body
```

Which makes since since @State things should be private.

What is the correct way to do this? I need to be able to access the sliderVal outside my view on a separate thread, so using a @Binding or @State doesn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56725084/swiftui-how-to-get-continuous-updates-from-slider), the trick is to move the $ and not use self:

```
struct ExampleView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var externalData : ExternalData

    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $externalData.sliderVal, from: 1, through: 100, by: 1)
    }

}

final class ExternalData : BindableObject {

    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<ExternalData, Never>()

    var sliderVal : Double = 5.0 {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
}
```