# SwiftUI: Displaying slider position in a seperate label

Tags: swiftui

This question is a bit of a follow on from [SwiftUI: How to get continuous updates from Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56725084/swiftui-how-to-get-continuous-updates-from-slider)

Basically I have a slider which is one of a number of sliders. Each on changes a parameter on a model class so I'm passing in a binding which represents a specific property on the model class. This works in that the model gets the new value each time the slider moves.

```swift
struct AspectSlider: View {

    private var value: Binding<Double>

    init(value: Binding<Double>, hintKey: String) {
        self.value = value
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Text("\(self.value.value)")
            Slider(value: Binding<Double>(getValue: { self.value.value }, setValue: { self.value.value = $0 }),
                    from: 0.0, through: 4.0, by: 0.5)
        }
    }
}
```

What isn't working correctly is the `Text("\(self.value.value)")` display which is meant to show the current value of the slider. It's not updating when the `Binding<Double>` value changes.

Instead it only updates when something else on the display triggers a display refresh. In my case the label that represents the result of the calculating performed by the model (which doesn't necessarily change when a slider changes it's value).

I've confirmed that the model is getting changes so the binding is updating. My question is why is the Text label not updating immediately.

Comment: It is working for me. Can you show us how are you instantiating the AspectSlider view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've worked out why my code wasn't updating as it should. It came down to my model which looks like this (Simple version):

```swift
final class Calculator: BindableObject {

    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
    var total: Int = 0
    var clarity: Double = 0.0 { didSet { calculate() }}

    private func calculate() {
        if newValue.rounded() != Double(total) {
            total = Int(newValue)
            didChange.send(self.total)
        }
    }
}
```

What was happening was that the value on the sider was only updating when this model executed the `didChange.send(self.total)` line. I think, if I've got this right, that because the label is watching a binding, only when the binding updates does the label update. Makes sense. Still working this out.

I guess it part of learning about Combine and how it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code, if called like this, works fine:

[image]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var value: Double = 0

    var body: some View {
        AspectSlider(value: $value, hintKey: "hint")
    }
}

struct AspectSlider: View {

    private var value: Binding<Double>

    init(value: Binding<Double>, hintKey: String) {
        self.value = value
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Text("\(self.value.value)")
            Slider(value: Binding<Double>(getValue: { self.value.value }, setValue: { self.value.value = $0 }),
                   from: 0.0, through: 4.0, by: 0.5)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you can also take advantage of the property wrapper `@Binding`, to avoid using `self.value.value`. Your implementation should change slightly:

```swift
struct AspectSlider: View {
    @Binding private var value: Double

    init(value: Binding<Double>, hintKey: String) {
        self.$value = value
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Text("\(self.value)")
            Slider(value: Binding<Double>(getValue: { self.value }, setValue: { self.value = $0 }),
                   from: 0.0, through: 4.0, by: 0.5)
        }
    }
}
```