# Is it possible to have a Service in SwiftUI and push data to a View and update the UI?

Tags: swift, service, websocket, swiftui, combine

I have a service file which gets and sends data to a backend. Is it possible to push push data from the service to a View and let the UI get the changes(not like a global var) like with a @State.

@EnviornmentObject isn't working read only
Global vars are not working because the don't inform the UI

```
import SwiftUI
import SocketIO
import Combine

let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:30000/ios")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
let socket = manager.defaultSocket

class Socket: BindableObject {
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<Socket,Never>()
    var sliderValue: Float = 6 {
        willSet {
            print(newValue)
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
    static let sharedInstance = Socket()
    init() {

        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
            print("socket connected")
            self.sliderValue = 8 
        }

    }


    func establishConnection() {
        socket.connect()
    }

    func closeConnection() {
        socket.disconnect()
    }
}
```

HomeView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var socketData: Socket

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
            Slider(value: $socketData.sliderValue, from: 0.0, through: 10.0)
            Text(String(socketData.sliderValue))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoa. `@EnvironmentObject` **is** correct. Update the model, send it to the UI, yada, yada. The issue is something else - and remember, `@State` is for local variable to a single `View`. So maybe... are you updating the model state correctly? Ae you dealing with a `UIKit` outlook for something *very* different? Why are you saying environment variables are read-only? They aren't. Please, show us more code to duplicate.

Comment: I thought I read that it is read only. I am new to swift but I updated the answer

Comment: Instead of posting a wordy answer that may not be of help, look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56725084/swiftui-how-to-get-continuous-updates-from-slider - a `Slider` is updating a `BindableObject`, which is either a `@EnvironmentObject` or a `@ObjectBinding` one. (And yeah, now in beta 4 it needs a `willSet` PassthruoghSubject. welcome to the bleeding edge of Swiftui!)

Comment: I did it like it was told there but when the socket connects the ui doesn't get updated

Comment: Are you updating the model on the main thread? That's the single caveat of using a `BindableObject` - and also why I'm not sure any of this can be of help. (I don't use sockets but know what they are - I've been in IT since 1984. If you can get things to work in `UIKit`... probably a `UIViewController`... do you think using a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` might work?)

Comment: I updated the code do I have to use a publisher or something like that when I set the var in the Socket class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have the problem that I can't get the data from the socket but normal Strings are working I will open a new question for this Problem:
[How to fix 'Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to type 'String' in coercion' error in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57114142/how-to-fix-cannot-convert-value-of-type-any-to-type-string-in-coercion-e)

I did had to use didSet here is the code:

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:30000/ios")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
let socket = manager.defaultSocket


class Socket: BindableObject {
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<Socket,Never>()
    var days: String = "Loading..." {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
    static let sharedInstance = Socket()
    init() {

        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
            print("socket connected")
        }
        socket.on("dailyWeather") {data, ack in
            print("just a test")
            self.days = "cur"
        }
    }


    func establishConnection() {
        socket.connect()
    }

    func closeConnection() {
        socket.disconnect()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your Socket hav a `messagePublisher` in order to update child views with incoming messages.

```
class Socket {
    static let sharedInstance = Socket()
    public let messagePublisher = PassthroughSubject<Message, Never>()
    init() {

      socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
          print("socket connected")
          let message = data as! Message
          messagePublisher.send(message)
      }

    }
}
```

Then Have your children subscribe to the incoming messages like so:

```
Socket.sharedInstance.assign(to: \.message, on: messageModel)
```

where `MessageModel` conforms to the `BindableObject` protocol

Comment: Where exactly do I have to add this line?Socket.sharedInstance.assign(to: \.message, on: messageModel)

Comment: @TobiasBauer you would add this in the child view where you'd like to use the socket. `DemoView` might have a property `@ObjectBinding var model: MessageModel`. And `MessageModel` should have a property `message` in which you can assign the socket.

Comment: I updated the above code but I have this error:Cannot convert value of type 'WritableKeyPath<HomeView, MessageModel>' to expected argument type 'ReferenceWritableKeyPath<_, MessageModel>'